# Trying to shorten this if-else sentence in a little game JAVA

Tags: java

I’m trying to make a little game where you must answer the results from the multiplication tables the thing is that when the program recieves the answer one by one I had to make 10 if statements for the 10 results, can I shorten it by even a bit?

I've been thinking but I couldn't come up with anything.

Here's the part of the code that recieves the answers (table is the number that the user chooses so he can answer from that especific table, for example the number 1 table) and P and E are the points and errors of the user that are later displayed.

```
System.out.println(table+"x1= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*1) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;
}
System.out.println(table+"x2= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*2) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x3= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*3) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x4= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*4) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x5= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*5) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x6= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*6) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x7= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*7) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x8= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*8) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x9= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*9) {
    System.out.println("Correct");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error");
    e +=1;}
System.out.println(table+"x10= ?");
r =sc.nextInt();
if(r == table*10) {
    System.out.println("Correct\n");
    p +=1;
}else {
    System.out.println("Error\n");
    e +=1;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should use loops (probably a `for` loop in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for loop for this. If you look at your code, you have a lot of blocks that do the same thing, but that varies by what you multiply the `table` with.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(table + "x" + i + "= ?");
    r = sc.nextInt();
    if(r == table * i) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        p += 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt think of that

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it to the `for-loop` cycle where the `i` is an interated reusable integer:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {                    // Iterate from 1 to 10 (11 is exlusive)
    System.out.println(table + "x" + i + "= ?");  // Here use "i" for the table name
    r = sc.nextInt();
    if (r == table * i) {                         // Here used "i" as multiplicator
        System.out.println("Correct");
        p += 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e += 1;
    }
}
```